# Apache POI missing dynamic library libfreetype.so

Tags: java, apache-poi, headless, netbsd

I use Apache POI to write out a spreadsheet. The problematic line is where I invoke `Sheet#autoSizeColumn(int column)`. If I run it on a unix shell with no graphical environment, the following exception appears:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/pkg/java/openjdk7/jre/lib/amd64/xawt/libmawt.so: Shared object "libXext.so.7" not found
```

According to [apache's quick guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Autofit) there is a property which should be set to signalize headless environment, so I try the following call:

```
 java -jar -Xmx200m -Djava.awt.headless=true myJar.jar
```

But I get then another exception for the same line:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/pkg/java/openjdk7/jre/lib/amd64/libfontmanager.so: Shared object "libfreetype.so.7" not found
```

The above apache guide also says "I should ensure that the fonts I use in your workbook are available to Java". I really don't use any specific fonts, the one and only thing I do with fonts is

```
XSSFFont boldFont = (XSSFFont) wb.createFont();
boldFont.setBold(true);
titleRowStyle.setFont(boldFont);
```

The unix shell runs

```
openjdk version "1.7.0-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-internal-pkgsrc_2015_01_06_05_56-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

and

```
NetBSD *** 6.1.5 NetBSD 6.1.5 (jajo) #1: Sun Jun 21 09:13:03 UTC 2015  spaj@***:/usr/src/sys/arch/amd64/compile/jajo amd64
```

Is it possible to fix this issue?

Comment: How did you install the JVM? Was it from a package? Did you skip any dependencies? Do you have freetype installed?

Comment: I am not the administrator of the target machine so unfortunately I cannot give you such details aboute the JVM installation.  Freetype seems to be installed because `freetype-config` is available.

Comment: You likely need to install the missing libraries on that machine to make it work.

Comment: @centic Is is possible to do this as non-root?

Comment: Usually this will require root-access as installing these adds system libraries. You could try installing them manually somewhere in the user-directory and adjusting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include these, but it sounds like a hack for a very common library which is usually required to have a fully working Java JRE installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an older library version in the system:

```
bash-4.3$ find /usr -name "libfreetype.*"
find: /usr/games/hide: Permission denied
/usr/pkg/lib/libfreetype.la
/usr/pkg/lib/libfreetype.a
/usr/pkg/lib/libfreetype.so
/usr/pkg/lib/libfreetype.so.6
/usr/pkg/lib/libfreetype.so.6.11.3
```

Then I created a symbolic link for the lastest available version as if it would be version 7:

```
ln -s /usr/pkg/lib/libfreetype.so.6.11.3 ~/tmp/lib/libfreetype.so.7
```

And start now my jar file with an environment variable:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/tmp/lib java -jar -Xmx200m -Djava.awt.headless=true myJar.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue similar to this. [Danny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34118478/apache-poi-missing-dynamic-library-libfreetype-so#answer-34257466) pointed me in the right direction. Basically, if the app is inside a [Tomcat Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat) container, make sure you are not using the slim version.

Using `tomcat:9.0.24-jdk11-openjdk-slim`, `find /usr -name libfreetype.*` shows that [FreeType `libfreetype`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/freetype/) was not included in the JVM. Updating the base image to `tomcat:9.0.24-jdk11-openjdk` resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

First, update your apt using RUN `apt update`;
and then install fontconfig libfreetype6 through the below command.

```
apt install -y fontconfig libfreetype6
```

I faced this for jdk11.