# Running spring boot native application getting the following error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, graalvm-native-image

While running a spring boot 3 native application on *bellsoft-liberica-vm-core-openjdk17-22.3.0* I'm getting this following error after creating the image.

`./target/blog: error while loading shared libraries: libfreetype.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

`mvn -Pnative native:compile` to create the image.

`./target/blog` to start the image.

Comment: Could you post output of `ldd ./target/blog` please? Is it JDK 11 or 17?

Comment: @peterz I'm using bellsoft-liberica-vm-core-openjdk17-22.3.0. Only creates a problem when using spring-data-jpa. 

`linux-vdso.so.1 
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libfreetype.so => not found
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a bit late, but I recently faced the same problem (using Ubuntu 22.04).

`apt-get install libfreetype-dev` will install the required library.

---

Or you might create a symlink to point to another installed version, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34257466

(`libfreetype6` may already be installed, otherwise it may be via `apt-get install libfreetype6`).

1. find the location of the installed library:

```
$ dpkg -L libfreetype6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
```

2. create a symlink:

```
$ ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 ~/tmp/lib/libfreetype.so
```

3. provide the symlink when running the native-image:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/tmp/lib ./build/native/nativeCompile/myAppNativeImage
```